# Delete process after excel Powershell script is run. What am i missing?

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to delete the processes in task manager after I finish this powershell script, but it still appears after the script is run. Any ideas?

```
    #Declarations
$dir = "mydirectory*"
$NewName = "mydirectory"+(Get-Date).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd")+".xlsx"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$latest.name

$excelObj = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excelObj.Visible = $False
$excelObj.DisplayAlerts = $False
$FileExists = Test-Path $NewName

if($FileExists -eq $True)

{#If todays file exists already
Write-Host –NoNewLine "File Already Exists, Refreshing..."
$workBook = $excelObj.Workbooks.Open($NewName)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item("DataV2") 
$worksheet.activate()
$workBook.RefreshAll()
Start-Sleep -s 10
$workBook.Save()
$excelObj.Quit()
#delete old files
(Get-ChildItem $dir -recurse | select -ExpandProperty fullname) -ne $NewName | remove-item
}

Else
{#If todays file does not exist
$workBook = $excelObj.Workbooks.Open($latest)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item("DataV2") 
$worksheet.activate()
$workBook.RefreshAll()
Start-Sleep -s 10
$workBook.SaveAs($NewName)
$excelObj.Quit()
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
#delete old files
(Get-ChildItem $dir -recurse | select -ExpandProperty fullname) -ne $NewName | remove-item}

#Remove Tasks and Prcesses
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excelObj)
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workBook)
Remove-Variable excelObj
Remove-Variable workBook
```

You can see at the end I run the ReleaseComObject stuff to clear the process.

Comment: Probably clean the objects in reverse order, that is, worksheet first, workbook second, application last.

Answer (score 2):

it's really annoying i know, one way is:

```
$workbook.Close()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$excelObj.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excelObj)
Remove-Variable excelObj
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

If it still there, this is the killer way :)

```
$excelObj.Visible = $true
$ProcID = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowHandle -eq $excelObj.HWND} | Select -ExpandProperty ID
$excelObj.Visible = $False
Get-Process -Id $ProcID | Stop-Process -Force
```

this one goes before the `$excelObj.Quit()`